# Net Core 2 Equivalent of HandleErrorAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-2.0

I am migrating .Net 4.6.2 project to Net Core 2.

What is the equivalent of `HandleErrorAttribute` ? Receiving Error below 2nd line

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new CustomerAuthorize());
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); 
}
```

**Error:**

```
The type or namespace name 'HandleErrorAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/2125006.aspx?How+to+use+exception+filters+in+the+asp+net+core+web+project

Answer (score 7):

In asp.net core, you could use [Exception Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#exception-filters).

We could create a custom Exception Filter like:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
....
....

public class HandleExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
 public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
 {
  var result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };
  var modelMetadata = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
  result.ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(
          modelMetadata, context.ModelState);
  result.ViewData.Add("HandleException", 
          context.Exception);
  context.Result = result;
  context.ExceptionHandled = true;
 }           
}
```

A filter can be added to the pipeline at one of three scopes. You can add a filter to a particular action method or to a controller class by using an attribute. Or you can register a filter globally for all controllers and actions. Filters are added globally by adding it to the MvcOptions.Filters collection in ConfigureServices:

```
 services.AddMvc(options=>options.Filters.Add(new HandleExceptionAttribute()));
```

Refer to [Create Custom Exception Filter In ASP.NET Core](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5df6e275-1148-45a1-a8b3-0ba2c7c9cea1.aspx).

Comment: thanks!, what do you think of the solution here? else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
    },    https://forums.asp.net/t/2125006.aspx?How+to+use+exception+filters+in+the+asp+net+core+web+project

Comment: It is the same.The link enables you to add logging to your filter which also inherits `ExceptionFilterAttribute`.`app.UseExceptionHandler("/error")` uses [Exception Handling Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#exception-handler-page) to configure a custom error handling page